# Replacing values in a particular column in a CSV file using R

Tags: r, csv

I am loading a dataset into R and performing some operations on the column named 'Income'. This is my code:

```
CustomerAnalysis <-read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\Hemanth\\Desktop\\509\\Marketing-Customer-Value-Analysis.csv", header=TRUE)
attach(CustomerAnalysis)
GenderSummary <- summary(Gender)
GenderSummary


Income
Income[Income==0] <- NA

Income[Income <= 29999] <- "Low"
Income[Income > 29999 & Income <= 69999 ] <- "Medium"
Income[Income > 70000] <- "High"
```

I am trying to categorize the 'Income' with "low", "medium" and "high". It is working fine till "Low" and "Medium", when it comes to "high", It is replacing all the values in the column 'Income' with "High" ,except for NA values.

after 'low':
[image: after 'low']

after 'medium':
[image: after 'medium':]

After 'High' it is changing to this:
[image: After 'High' it is changing to this.]

I don't know what's wrong. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: produce a sample of your data ,else it would be impossible to answer

Comment: Just to make you understand whats going wrong
"low" > 70000
[1] TRUE

Comment: It didn't work with your code because you are converting the `Income` to character class `Income[Income <= 29999] <- "Low"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. I changed the "High" statement to :

```
Income[Income >= 70000 & Income != "Low" & Income != "Medium" ] <- "High"
```

and it worked.

I don't understand why it didn't work earlier. Any ideas?